Among traditions of world music, is European classical the only one with a tradition of separate composer roles?
Over the past century and a half of Western classical music, there has been a dichotomy between the role of the composer and the performer. Has this tendency occurred commonly in other music traditions aside from those that have descended from Western classical music?
For example in Jazz, there are occasional composers like Gil Evans but most like Ellington performed with the band. American Pop music has composers and performers. Both those also descended in part from Western classical.
The source of my question centers around wanting to know how common it is in various traditions of music for a composer to write music for other people to perform. For purposes of this question, I see that as distinct from people who write music for themselves to perform individually or part of a group (for example, like most rock bands).
So are there other musics throughout the world such as West African Drumming, Gamelan, South Indian, or Gwana with composers who write music for other people to play?

Comments have been moved to chat; please do not continue the discussion here. Before posting a comment below this one, please review the purposes of comments. Comments that do not request clarification or suggest improvements usually belong as an answer, on [meta], or in [chat]. Comments continuing discussion may be removed.

I'm working on a rather long answer, but halfway through, I realize I might be addressing more what I've gleaned from the comment thread than your original wording. I was answering the question as if it were: "Are there cultures that recognize 'composer' as a distinct role, i.e. a person is more recognized as a composer than as a performer?"

But re-reading the question, as it stands, it seems to be more about the nature of transmission than about roles: "Are there cultures that separate the act of composition from the act of performance, so that someone might write with no intention of performing their own work?" The latter question is a prerequisite for the former; you can't have a full-time composer without the notion of composition. But the question of roles pulls in more considerations. If that's really what you're looking for, please edit along those lines.

I’m commenting again to explain my close vote and down vote: this question makes no sense to me because no matter what is meant by “European classical tradition”, it is not at all common for composers to not also perform, especially if we consider conducting to be performing. On the other side, it’s trivially true that there are distinct actions of composing and performing in all musical traditions, since performers today play music written by composers no longer living in every tradition I'm aware of. So this question has a false assumption and requires more detail to help it make sense.

I'm just curious why is it so important if the composer did also perform or not, when the performances themselves have been lost and all that we know is the sheet music and maybe some written descriptions?

IN PROGRESS: it's taking me multiple sittings to answer this question so I'm posting a partial answer to save it, and will add more.

I choose to answer this question in less absolute terms than it was phrased. Questions along the lines of "are there any instances of X" are problematic because, if there is even a single instance, then they are far too easy to answer and the answers lack depth ("Sure, this one; done"), but it is impossible to say with certainty "No, there are no instances of X in all the musics of the world" unless one is in fact familiar with all the musics of the world." (And it's very easy to disprove such an answer with just one discovery. There are similar problems with "what's the first instance of X.")
So I choose to answer the question as "How common, across global musical traditions, is it for the culture to recognize a role of 'composer,' a person who primarily writes music rather than perform it?" And the short answer is "very rare indeed."
First, since there was some confusion in the comments, we need to distinguish between the concept of attribution and the concept of primary role. That is, we're not looking only for cultures that say "this tune was written by so-and-so," or even that distinguish the act of composing from the act of performing, but for those that describe a person primarily as a composer and not as a performer. Even music cultures in which most pieces are usually unattributed might have some with attributed composers: the Irish harpist Turlough O’Carolan has many tunes attributed to him, but was also a celebrated performer.
Let's also recognize, off the bat, that the phenomenon described does to some extent exist. When I was in conservatory, some of my classmates were composition majors, i.e. "were composers" and were studying to make a profession of it. Now, they also had experience making music. A follow-up question for such a person would often be "oh cool; what's your primary instrument?" They were often (but not always? I'm not sure) required to participate in ensembles like orchestra or choir. And some did also pursue performance at the same time, whether as a major or informally. But the fact remains that there were those who identified solely as "composers" and I don't remember them ever performing, but rather trying to convince others to play their compositions.
So the premise stands. But even within Western classical music, it's fairly recent, and fairly rare. This just makes sense; it's hard to create anything in a "language" that you've never "spoken." So it would be unusual, maybe impossible, for anyone to compose without having had experience in making music. So it's unusual to find a composer who has never been a performer; what we find more often is people who have been performers, but whose role as a composer might eclipse that role.

Things I intend to touch on in future edits:

Conceptual prerequisites for this concept:

composition (a lasting aesthetic object can be re-created via transmissible instructions)
attribution (the lasting aesthetic object was "invented" by an individual)


the relationship of composed material to improvised material: cf jazz & Indian classical
non-performing pop hit songwriters like Diane Warren
classical precedents: Lully, Gesualdo? "Composer" perhaps more common before the era of public performance?


Don't want to complicate your plan further (looking forward to reading your finished answer, BTW), but do you plan to include the case where an orchestra's music director / conductor creates an arrangement / adaptation for his/her orchestra to perform?  I heard that in a marching bands this often happens, to tailor the piece to specific band instruments' availability.  Or is "arrangement" out of scope of the question?  For example, my pipe organ professor did his own organ "transcription" of a Bach's orchestral piece that is not merely transcription.

@GratefulDisciple And of course the significance of arrangement can vary, from rewriting a clarinet part for saxophone to arranging a symphony for guitar quartet.

Exactly.  So in those situations, if the arranger takes part in the performance, even as a conductor, would that count as "separate composer role"?  Another point to consider is film music, or in the world setting, "composer" for Gamelan music intended to accompany dance / wayang who may or may not take part in the performance (see examples).

Would video game music, film music, etc. count as non-Western if the composer is Asian/African/etc.? The music plays by itself, and even when their composers play that music, it's almost always merely an arrangement of the full version (except for music literally for solo piano/etc.).

@AndyBonner Yes! Thank you! "How common, across global musical traditions, is it for the culture to recognize a role of 'composer,' a person who primarily writes music rather than perform it?" Is really at the heart of the question I'm trying to get to because my assumption is "very rare indeed" is the correct answer. It seems that separation from "creator" and "doer" is a very modern (note the small "m" - I'm not referring here to "Modernism") European practice similar to the idea in European science that one can be an impartial outside observer.

@AndyBonner I mark this correct now but I look forward to further edits and thoughts if you have the time.

@Rozgonyi Thanks, and sorry to have left it half-finished. You might still edit the question a bit to focus on "composer as a distinct identity" rather than on "one person writes, another performs." Beethoven was, even in his time, recognized more as a composer than a performer, but still played his own piano works.

@Dekkadeci It depends on a couple things. First if its an Asian/African person composing for a symphony or other European ensemble, it is at least western influenced so I wouldn't consider that as an option. Second, if someone records African drumming that is used in a video game, that's still the performer composing - no separation.
